# ParserError: Expected primary expression. when using payable

Tags: solidity, payable

I have the following code:

```
    function payout() public payable {    
        uint ordersLength = orders.length;    
        uint totalRaised = 0;    
        for (uint i = 0; i < ordersLength; i++) {    
            totalRaised += orders[i].amount;    
            emit Amount(orders[i].amount);    
        }    
        for (uint i = 0; i < ordersLength; i++) {    
            payable(orders[i].investor).transfer(msg.value * orders[i].amount / totalRaised);        
            emit onPayout(orders[i].investor, creator, orders[i].investorId, creationId, creatorId, block.timestamp,        
                         msg.value * orders[i].amount / totalRaised);    
        }    
    }
```

But upon compiling the contract, I'm getting this error:

```
project:/contracts/Creation.sol:59:13: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
            payable(orders[i].investor).transfer(msg.value * orders[i].amount / totalRaised);
            ^-----^
```

How to fix this?

Comment: why do you have a contract named payable ? isn't that a special keyword in solidity?, change that name and see if the error eliviates.

Comment: What Solidity version are you using ? The payable() function has been introduced in 0.6.0

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you are using a compiler version older than 0.6.

The solution is to use a compiler version more than or equals to 0.6 OR you can declare the `investor` field in your struct as `address payable` instead of `address` and you will not need to use the payable function because you will be able to transfer/send directly like this:

```
orders[i].investor.transfer(msg.value * orders[i].amount / totalRaised
```